# What triggers iOS 5.0 cache purge?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

As of iOS 5.0 Apple began to purge or clean the Caches directory inside individual applications when it decided the device was using too much space.  Can anyone point me to the location of documentation or anecdotal information regarding at which threshold this cache cleaning occurs (for instance 90%+ disk usage) and how often it is checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my my testing, it seems that the wipe happens to all not currently running applications when the space usage on the device EXCEEDS the reported amount of space available (seems iPhone lies about space available to prevent you from getting into reserved space).  When you cross that line, a dialogue pops up:

[image: iPhone too much space Dialogue]

And when you hit done, it then wipes the space.  This is the only situation that I was able to reliably reproduce to trigger the wipe (for testing / etc), and I did so by filling my device as much as I could with movies and music, and then downloading big files in DropBox.

Answer (score 2):

as far as i know there hasn't been any official information about when the purge happens and - to be honest - you shouldn't be trying to predict it. it IS a problem, though. thankfully, apple has realised this and as of iOS 5.0.1 you can set a "do not backup" flag:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

so you'll want to place those files in your app's Documents/ dir or your apps Library/Private Documents/ and set the "do not backup" attribute.

Comment: Maybe not predict it, but reproducing it would be nice.  Specifically on iOS 5.0.0 there is no fix in our situation (for security reasons we were storing our files in Caches to prevent backup) but then they started getting purged.  We now keep it in a private directory for iOS 5.0.1+ (With the do-not-backup flag set) but for iOS 5.0 we have not fix (Can't backup, can't purge), other then to give the user a heads up that they might lose their data, before it happens.

Comment: So can we just have "do not purge" flag set so that it works on IOS 5.0.1? Will apple still reject app?